# Getting value from Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advance Custom Fields plugin in my WordPress website. I have created a template page and set it for home page.  In ACF plugin I created a new Field Group called Travel Form and in it a field called locations. please check below screenshot

[image]

In my template I'm calling it by name locations throught ACF function but I'm not able to fetch it.

this is my code

```
 <?php
    /*
  Template Name: Home Page
  */
  $field = get_field_object('locations');
  print_r($field); die;
 ?>
```

Where is my mistake? Please tell me. I'm not able to get all locations.

Comment: If you want to get the selected value for the `locations` field the correct function is just `get_field( 'locations' );` not `get_field_object()`.

Comment: Can you explain whether you're wanting to display the select field with all the options, so the user can choose on the homepage itself - or whether you are setting the value in wp-admin and just want to display the selected value on the homepage?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [get_field_object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/), which isn't correct.

What you should be using is [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) or [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

**Example get_field():**

```
$value = get_field( "locations" );

if( $value ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

**Example the_field():**

```
<p><?php the_field('locations'); ?></p>
```

**Note:**  ACF has [great documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/), you should look it over.